# my IDE doesn't display the window it suppose to display despite not having any errors in my code, how can i fix this

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets

I am doing my first program using wxwidets and i am using visual studio 2019 community, the program should show an empty window but when I pressed debug on my IDE the debug finished with no errors but it didn't show the window, I cheeked the code many times and couldn't find any error, .it also show many warnings the first one's code is c28251 and it say"Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': this instance has no annotations"

FrameOne.h:-

```
#include<wx/wx.h>
class FrameOne :public wxFrame
{
public:
    FrameOne();

};
```

FrameOne.cpp

```
include"FrameOne.h"
FrameOne::FrameOne():wxFrame(nullptr,wxID_ANY,"Simple",wxPoint(200,200),wxSize(300,300))
{}
```

main.h

```
#include<wx/wx.h>
#include"FrameOne.h"
class strtmain :public wxApp
{
public:
    strtmain();
    ~strtmain();
    virtual bool InOnit();

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(strtmain);
strtmain::strtmain()
{
}
strtmain::~strtmain()
{
}

bool strtmain::InOnit()
{
    FrameOne* simple = new FrameOne();
    simple->Show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: did you build the program as Windows or a console application? Also, can you build and run the minimal sample? And did you build the library yourself or you are using the pre-built binaries?

Comment: i build it as window, i can run the sample,i build my self

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to override `wxApp::OnInit()`, not `InOnit()`.

The warning is unrelated, and apparently there's a [bug](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18529) for it too.